# "<script type="text/javascript">" unexpected token jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.mgaf_opts_list.mgaf_single_opt_opts li').click(function() {
    $('#theImg').hide();
   });
   });
</script>
```

When I run this inside console without the script tags, it works fine, but adding script tags seem to be causing a conflict even thought they are correct?

Comment: You are adding script tags in the console? The console is not expecting HTML.

Comment: ok. but when i insert this inline with the script tags on the page, it does not run. i have other jquery snippets working on the same page so jquery is def loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags are meant for HTML and would only work when executed on a browser. The console will not recognize the Script tags.

Comment: understood, but there still seems to be an issue when adding it inline